# Knockout js hide image div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, knockout.js

I am having the `Div binding` the image tag,it is working,but when the image value is null.

i want hide whole div,but when the image value is null i get blank white border box, i need to remove that also.how to archive this using `knockout js`

```
<ul  id="user-listview" data-bind="foreach:dataItems">
   <li>
       <div>
         <span data-bind="text:UserID"  ></span>
          <span data-bind="text:UserName" ></span>
           <span data-bind="text:mobilenumber"></span>
         </div>
      <div id="divuserImage">
         <span data-bind="text:ImageID" style="display:none"></span>
         <img style="height: 200px;width: 300px;margin-top: 10px;" data-bind="attr: { src:userImageUrl }" />
     </div>
  </li>
</ul>

function UserModel(data){
    self=this;
    self.UserID=ko.observable(data.UserID)
    self.UserName=ko.observable(data.UserName)
    self.mobilenumber=ko.observable(data.mobilenumber)
    self.userImageUrl=ko.observable(data.userimage)
    self.ImageID=ko.observable(data.ImageID)
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, if you haven't already

```
<ul  id="user-listview" data-bind="foreach:dataItems">
    <li>
        <div>
            <span data-bind="text:UserID"  ></span>
            <span data-bind="text:UserName" ></span>
            <span data-bind="text:mobilenumber"></span>
        </div>
        <div id="divuserImage" data-bind="visible: userImageUrl() && userImageUrl() != ' '">
            <span data-bind="text:ImageID" style="display:none"></span>
            <img style="height: 200px;width: 300px;margin-top: 10px;" data-bind="attr: { src:userImageUrl }" />
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I've only added the data-bind="visible: userImageUrl()" in the div tag

In your js model you also need a self.ImageID property(or if you add it to each element in dataItems in some other way). For example:

```
function UserModel(data){
    self=this;
    self.UserID=ko.observable(data.UserID)
    self.UserName=ko.observable(data.UserName)
    self.mobilenumber=ko.observable(data.mobilenumber)
    self.userImageUrl=ko.observable(data.userimage)
    self.ImageID=ko.observable(data.ImageID)
}
```

Comment: i tried, didnt worked for me, if the value is null also its taking blank white border of width and hieght

Comment: Is the code in the question all your code for this div or is there something else you are doing to manipulate the div?

Comment: its binding in foreach loop  list, each list value  will have different images, if the images has value it should disaply else its should hide whole "divuserImage"

Comment: Does your HTML look like in the edited question? Could you show us how it looks including the foreach?

Comment: Oh, and by the way, does each list value contain an ImageID property too(in the function UserModel)? Otherwise the knockout bindings will crash and then you might see an empty bordered square

Comment: Do you get any errors in the debugging console of your browser?

Comment: no i am not getting any error, but stil if image value is not there i get blank border and it takes height and width

Comment: If you have the data-bind="visible: userImageUrl()", and the parentheses are important, on your divuserImage like in my example and the value of userImageUrl is really a value that js regards as null(it can be null, undefined, an empty string, but not a string with a single blank space for example) then you should not get the bordered square

Comment: still not working, i did same like you have shown in above code

Comment: Hmm, strange! Is there any way you could give us some input data, in json or however you are receiving it, especially an example of when there is no image url?

Comment: In a comment on the other answer you wrote "src =" " but i am binding the image in list", which suggests there might be a single space in the value of userImageUrl, i have edited my answer to handle this case aswell

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS to do this. Providing if there isnt anything in src if null you can simply use:

```
#divuserImage img[src=""] {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: @kittysarvaj what is in src?

Comment: src =" " but i am binding the image in list